# Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.x : DateFormat throws null Pointer

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am trying to upgrade spring data elastic search from 4.1.10 to 4.2.2

I have a date field definition like below

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.date_optional_time, index = false) 
private LocalDate executionDate;
```

It works with spring data elastic search 4.1.10 but fails in 4.2.x (4.2.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.0).

Getting the below error while bean instantiation of repository.

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Class.isEnum()" because "componentType" is null**

Using the keyword **"format"** or **"pattern"** **inside @Field throws this error** in 4.2.x not the case in 4.1.10.

Any suggestion would greatly help .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you provide the complete code for the entity class or a reproducible example? I just tried a Spring Boot 2.5.0 application that uses Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.1 with an entity that contains the property you show, but there is no error, the index and mapping are created without any problems.